# GLM R-plot: linear relationship?

Tags: categorical-data, generalized-linear-model, glmm

I constructed GLM's to compare a set of variables before constructing GLMM (to model habitat selection). I also wanted to see if there were linear relationships between the response variable and the explanatory variables.
I have a response binary variable, which correspond to used or available (1/0) locations of several individuals (which is the reason I will construct GLMM, to include them as a random effect).

First question: since GLMM can handle non-linear variables (correct me if I am wrong), is it important to test linear relationships before constructing GLMMs?

Second question: I plotted one of the models and I don't know how to interpretate the plot. I present the summary and the plot below.

Here is the summary of the model:

```
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.5364  -0.5364  -0.4028  -0.2793   2.6059  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.42919    0.02177 -111.58   <2e-16 ***
LC2_z       -0.57874    0.02361  -24.51   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 19905  on 32669  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 19191  on 32668  degrees of freedom
AIC: 19195
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

How do I interpretate this? Is it normal to have these two lines?

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that it makes no sense to say there is a "linear relationship" between a dichotomous response variable and an independent variable.  That's one reason we use logistic regression (or other transformations of the response).

Also, perhaps it's just a sort of typo, but variables can't be linear.  Did you mean "non-continuous"?

Finally, if you need a mixed model (to deal with dependent data) then any model which does not account for the dependency may be very misleading.

Comment: I am not an expert at all in statistics, but I saw this in a paper (regarding habitat selection, and with the same kind of variables as I have): "In order to avoid linearity assumptions, we preliminarily explored the shape of the response for each landscape variable before fitting them into the final equations". (Then they used GAMs, and later GLMM) That is why I decided to construct these models with each variable; but since GLMMs account for that, I am not sure now if this analysis makes sense!  Should I construct GLMM with each variable then?